# Как выбрать все элементы массива кроме текущего? JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Здрасьти, собственно как выбрать все элементы массива в цикле кроме i?

```js
function hover(className) {
  let hov = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for (let i = 0; i < hov.length; i++) {
    hov[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
      hov[i].classList.add("active");
    });
    hov[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {

      hov[i].classList.remove("active");
    });
  }
}
hover("item")
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 150vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.active {
  width: 40vw!important;
}

.not-active {
  width: 15vw!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Пока реализовал так

```js
function hover(className) {
  let hov = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  document.body.addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
    for (let i = 0; i < hov.length; i++) {
      hov[i].classList.add("not-active");
    }
  });
  document.body.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
    for (let i = 0; i < hov.length; i++) {
      hov[i].classList.remove("not-active");
    }
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < hov.length; i++) {
    hov[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', e => {
      hov[i].classList.add("active");
    });
    hov[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {

      hov[i].classList.remove("active");
    });
  }
}
hover("item")
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 150vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.not-active {
  width: 15vw!important;
}

.active {
  width: 40vw!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: вы явно что-то делаете не так, табы?

Comment: `HTML` приложили бы.

Comment: @doox911, добавил html. Нужно .not-active как-то передать другим элементам

Comment: если я правильно понял то нужно класс `not-active` удалить и сделать так : `.item {
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 10vw;
}

.item.active {
  width: 40vw;
}`

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych, не, нужно `not-active` добавлять туда где нет класса `active`. Но сама идея в том, что когда наводишь на элемент он увеличивается, остальные уменьшаются. Пока реализовал неуклюже, при наведении на родителя всем прописывается `not-active`, а потом с помощью `active` всё это перекрываю:

Comment: @AndreyGrek тоесть изначально на елементах нету класса `not-active`, потом при наведении он добавляеться, а когда же его убирать со всех елементов ?

Comment: @Rostyslav Kuzmovych, дополнил свой вопрос реализацией, хотелось бы такой же функционал, но менее костыльный :)

Comment: @AndreyGrek я там примерчик простой запостил, смотрите )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно вот так сделать :

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 150vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body:hover .item {
  width: 15vw;
}

.item {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

body .item:hover {
  width: 40vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

Comment: Действительно :D
Спасибо! Что-то к вечеру совсем голова квадратная стала))